# If Else Range Search Python 3.5

Tags: python, xml, csv, if-statement, range

I am trying to use Python 3.5 to create a .xml document from csv.  The .xml requires a specific schema, which I have been able to replicate through Python.  My issue is that some of the schema needs to be changed, depending on input from the csv.  If a specific product is listed in the csv, a couple of lines from the xml need to be left out.  I have provided a basic example below; the issue lies in the middle of the code, where I try to call a defined variable string and do the if else statement on the range to eliminate the unneeded lines.  No matter what I do the else is defaulted to; the if portion never solves true although the data in the source document matches the defined variable string, thus the two lines for the range are always left out -thanks in advance.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding= utf-8

import csv

csvFile = 'PRODUCT LIST.csv'
xmlFile = 'PRODUCT LIST.xml'

csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
var1 = 'CocaCola'

xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + "\n")
# there must be only one top-level tag

xmlData.write('<ArrayOfProducts>' + "\n")

rowNum = 0

for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        tags = row
        # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
        for i in range(0, 12):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')

      xmlData.write('  <Product>' + "\n")
      xmlData.write('    <Name />' + "\n")

      for i in range(0, 2):
            xmlData.write('    ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")

      xmlData.write('    <List>' + "\n")

      for i in range(2, 3):
            xmlData.write('      <List ' + "p:type=" + '"' + row[i] + '"' + ' ' + "xmlns:p=" '"xsi"' '>' "\n")

      for i in range(3, 7):
            xmlData.write('        ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")

      if i in range(3,4) == var1:
          for i in range(7, 9):
              xmlData.write('        ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")

      else:
          pass

      xmlData.write('        <Supported>' + "\n")

      for i in range (9, 10):
             xmlData.write('      <Manufacturer ' + "p:type=" + '"' + row[i] + '"' + '>' "\n")

      for i in range(10, 11):
            xmlData.write('            ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")

      xmlData.write('          </Manufacturer>' + "\n")
      xmlData.write('        </Supported>' + "\n")

      for i in range(11, 12):
         xmlData.write('        ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                        + row[i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")

      xmlData.write('      </Manufacturer>' + "\n")
      xmlData.write('    </List>' + "\n")
      xmlData.write('  </Product>' + "\n")

    rowNum +=1
xmlData.write('</ArrayOfProducts>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to even tell what you're asking. There are only two `if` statements in your code. Only one has an `else` clause. That `else` clause is empty. The other `if` statement looks like you just took `for` and changed it to `if` and... I can't even figure out what you're trying to do. `if i in range(3, 4)` is just a very weird way of saying `if i == 3` for example, and you then compare that result (which will be `True` or `False`) to a string... which is an error in Python 3, but that's not the problem you say you're having. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You should not have to script XML tags and attributes as Python has modules to create XML documents with `createElement` and `setAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments gentlemen.  I never did find a solution; the software I am using requires a very rigid xml code, and I was able to use the above to generate the required xml from csv.  Kindall, I used the range function to call the different headers of the csv; you're obviously correct, i could have skipped range and gone to "if i==3' in cases where the desired column was only 1, but for the rest the ranges worked for me.  it's not pretty, but in the end it worked; the software accepted the extra lines that I was unable to eliminate from specific csv triggers.  thanks again.